# What is gcc 4.1.3?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc

According to the gcc releases page, http://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html, version 4.1.3 does not exist.

However, I've seen the version mentioned in various places. (Just do a Google search, for instance.) I also distinctly remember that 4.1.3 is the version I had in an old Ubuntu distro, and 4.1.3 is the version running in a chroot jail I still have.

So what **is** 4.1.3? More importantly, how does it differ from 4.1.2, and how can I get the source code for 4.1.3 so I can rebuild it on my system?

Comment: We don't speak of the Devil's Compiler.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to migrate to a more recent version?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't, because I run an online judge and I don't want to break old submissions.

Comment: Hmmm; you'd rather break new submissions that use more recent features and don't pander to the bugs in 4.1.3? I had a feeling there would be a sufficiently good reason, but I will note that most people will be unable to test with the compiler you use on their own machines.  2007 is quite a while ago.  Maybe you should check the old submissions against the new compiler, and simply mark as 'once valid but no longer' for those that don't work with the new compiler (which I'd expect to be a small minority). Maybe you should announce that you'll change reference compilers on 2014-07-01, and do it?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler A lot of people are used to 4.1.3, which is pretty lax about which headers you have to include, and has the useful <? and >? operators. Anyway I also offer a newer version, 4.8.1 (soon to be upgraded to 4.9.0).

Comment: OK; you know your business.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to some logs, this version of GCC was a *prerelease*.

> gcc (GCC) 4.1.3 20070929 (prerelease) (Ubuntu 4.1.2-16ubuntu2)

The source code for this version can be found on github [1]. Actually, GCC 4.1.3 has never been released. Finally, it is amusing to note that GCC 4.1.2-RH is based on 137441 of FSF branches/gcc-4_1-branch (the branch that contains the GCC 4.1.3 prerelease commit).

> [1] https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/commit/c87ea92b952cab1e97ef4ebc05f0a2c65e41fc6f

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the actual date returned by `--version` is 20080704, which was the most recent "daily bump" on that branch.