# boost unordered map in shared memory using std::string key

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible to use std::string or other complex structure key type with boost unordered map on shared memory?  If so, can I find some sample code? I found some sample code for using unordered map on shared memory but were unable to change the key type to complex structure. Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean with "shared memory"? Are you running a multi-threaded application and want to share a map between the threads? If so, how do you achieve the multithreading (pthreads, std::thread, boost::thread, tbb, OpenMP ...)?

Comment: Basically we need a big "Map" mapping ip addresses to user info (a structure) and we are currently doing it with boost::unordered_map. It's working fine using char[] as key, in one process. We need move the Map to shared memory so multiple processes can "look up" in the shared Map.  We need some sample code to help this move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

You can see an example here:

- [Boost interprocess unordered_map compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29557680/boost-interprocess-unordered-map-compilation/29558548#29558548)

You will want to watch the overhead when doing lookups. Using non-standard key equality/hash functions can solve this:

- [want to efficiently overcome mismatch between key types in a map in Boost.Interprocess shared memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328835/want-to-efficiently-overcome-mismatch-between-key-types-in-a-map-in-boost-interp/27330042#27330042)

  Note that that answer concerns itself with *ordered* containers

Comment: Thanks for the sample links. However, I was unable to compile the first one, it gives me an error expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token on the line ComplexType(std::string, Alloc2 const& alloc = {}) : map(alloc) {}. My compiler might be too old: gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)

Comment: Your compiler is too old. Just use c++03 equivalents (`= Alloc2()` here). Anyhoops: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6d02ba11c5520d4)**